# What motivated the Green headbands to genocide the Malay Chinese?

Tags: politics, the-windup-girl

In Bacigalupi's [The Windup Girl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Windup_Girl) the Green headbands, a fundamentalist Islamic movement in the 23rd century, genocide the native Malay-Chinese people causing the main Character Hock Seng to lose his entire extended family and his trading empire.

In the book, I don't remember an exact detailing of what set-off the Green Headbands, because that subplot is told mostly from Hock Seng's perspective.   Hock Seng didn't understand the threat the Green Headbands posed before the Genocide, and thus didn't fear the movement until it was too late.

The novel focuses on the threat of future bio-engineered plagues and the resulting loss of life and panic that they cause.  Cibiscosis, for instance, is particularly feared because it results in a fatal bloody hacking cough and kills crops as well.

I can't quite remember why the Green headbands genocided the Chinese, possible reasons include:

- Rumors of infected Chinese immigrants
- A bio-plague that targets Chinese
- A bio-plague in mainland china
- General fear combined with racism and religion
- Some combination of the above

Can anyone remind me why the Green headbands genocided the Malay Chinese?
<sub>(any quotes would be nice, but not required)</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I’m not sure this issue is thoroughly explained, though there are strong hints at religious persecution.

I could not find / cannot remember any reference to your first 3 suggestions (Rumors of infected Chinese immigrants, A bio-plague that targets Chinese, A bio-plague in mainland china)

Your 4th suggestion “General fear combined with racism and religion” is hinted at both in The Windup Girl and in “Yellow Card Man”, the related prequel novellete.

Here’s a reference to hatred in The Windup Girl

> Hock Seng has heard that cheshires were supposedly created by a calorie executive-some PurCal or AgriGen man, most likely-for a daughter's birthday. A party favor for when the little princess turned as old as Lewis Carroll's Alice.
>   The child guests took their new pets home where they mated with natural felines, and within twenty years, the devil cats were on every continent and Felis domesticus was gone from the face of the world, replaced by a genetic string that bred true ninety-eight percent of the time. The Green Headbands in Malaya hated Chinese people and cheshires equally, but as far as Hock Seng knows, the devil cats still thrive there.

And a reference confirming the religious fanaticism of the Green Headbands (at least in Hock Seng’s mind)

> As he scans the room, religious fanatics in green headbands leap from the shadows, machetes whirling, but they are only memories.

In “Yellow Card Man” (written before The Windup Girl) Hock Seng (“Tranh” in the novellete: it’s rumoured that the name change was because Tranh was too Vietnamese-sounding) at one point thinks about the issue

> And isn't that why the Green Headbands in Malaya hated us Chinese? Because we looked so good? Because we looked so rich? Because we spoke so well and worked so hard when they were lazy and we sweated every day?

And later

> If we had assimilated in Malaya like the Chiu Chow did here, would we have survived? 
>   Tranh shakes his head at the thought. It would have been impossible. His clan would have had to convert to Islam as well, and forsake all their ancestors in Hell. It would have been impossible. Perhaps it was his people's karma to be destroyed. To stand tall and dominate the cities of Penang and Malacca and all the western coast of the Malayan Peninsula for a brief while, and then to die.

I remember that there are other allusions to the economic status of the Chinese, ie. that they were hated because they were rich (compared to the Muslims) (I believe Hafiz alluded to that in a flashback), but I could not find a quote to support that. There are also references to the Chinese as 'the yellow people', hence yellow cards, so racism may also have played a part - though it is unclear whether that was an issue in Malaya or Bangkok (or both).

It’s probably meant to be portrayed as a complicated question, just like in real life parallels.